# Find shortest path in graph with a set starting node and that goes through a subset of nodes

Tags: python, graph-theory, traveling-salesman

Basically my goal is to find the target node to solve the TSP. In order to find this target node I need to know the shortest path between two nodes, specifying only the starting point where:

- The minimum cost path visits all nodes in subset of nodes.
- Cost is minimum.

My return function would return a NodeId which would be interpreted as the target node ID.

Any pseudocode would be appreciated.

Comment: That is exactly what Ford's and Dijkstra's algorithm are doing: finding shortest path from a starting node to any other nodes.

Answer (score 0):

You want the minimum spanning tree algorithm, modified to span your subset of nodes.

Here is how it goes:

```
- LOOP over every pair of nodes in the subset
  - APPLY Dijkstra algorithm to find shortest path between node pair.
- CREATE new graph, containing only the nodes in the subset
- ADD links between nodes in new graph with cost equal to length of shortest path between them in original graph.
- APPLY minimum spanning tree algorithm
- For links in the spanning tree, replace with nodes and links on shortest path between nodes in original graph.
```

This will give you the shortest tree that includes every node in the subset.

I do not know what you mean by "target node".  Please clarify what this is.